# Button is disabled after adding a command

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

May be look silly. Could not able to figure out,when command binding,button disabled sample code here,

I have custom control,

```
public class Stepper: ListBox
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Internal command used by the XAML template (public to be available in the XAML template). Not intended for external usage.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly RoutedCommand BackCommand = new RoutedCommand();

        static Stepper()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UXStepper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Stepper)));
        }

        public UXStepper()
        {
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(BackCommand, (o, e) => ZoomFit(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));
        }

        private void ZoomFit()
        {
            //some implementation
        }
}
```

**XAML code**

```
 <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Content="Back"
         Command="{x:Static shui:Stepper.BackCommand}"/>
```

Comment: to be honest i can not understand what are you trying to achieve? :)

Comment: @Zer0 my button is disabled everytime.

Comment: @Zadalaxmi: Where is the `Stepper`control located in your XAML and how does it relate to the `Button` that invokes the command?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right: your problem is that the binding does not work

- if you want to bind something with some static property than you have to define a source

```
<Window.Resources>
    <shui:Stepper x:Key="stepper"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Back"
        Command="{BackCommand, Source={StaticResource stepper}}"/>
```

- or you can simply bind it to your Singleton (if you have one)

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Back"
        Command="{BackCommand, Source={x:Static shui:Stepper.Instance}}"/>
```